# How to upgrade Kubuntu 20.10 to 21.04?

Tags: kubuntu, 20.10, do-release-upgrade, 21.04

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.10"
VERSION_ID="20.10"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=groovy
UBUNTU_CODENAME=groovy

$ cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting and upgrade behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for, or allow upgrading to, a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the supported release that immediately succeeds the
#           currently-running release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that if this option is used and
#           the currently-running release is not itself an LTS release the
#           upgrader will assume prompt was meant to be normal.
Prompt=normal

$ sudo do-release-upgrade -m DESKTOP
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
```

Am I missing something?
I thought it would become available @ 22.04.2021, but apparently not for everyone?

Comment: Please, wait until the first week of May. ***Upgrade*** is never made immediately available upon a new Ubuntu release.

Comment: If you read the release notes (I copied part of them into the answer I just marked duplicate to, but you may have trouble reading that), it highlights a bug that may cause updated machines to fail to boot in certain circumstances (which are given), thus the delay.  The delay actually is normal, as the upgrade is turned on **after** the ISO release, not at the ISO release (ISO being for new installs).